Debugging MAUI Blazor App in Chrome style or getting errors seen
I try to migrate my web Blazor app to MAUI.
I'm curious, if there is the way to see tools like Chrome 'Console', 'Network' etc. while debugging MAUI Blazor app on Windows?
The source of the question is my triage to migrate web app (Blazor) to desktop with plans to do so on mobile?
Does somebody of you, community, tried to do so? The first experience I've got is getting instant error and 'loading...' message with asking to reload page - that's not very informative.
It would be much more helpful to see error details or to get access to tools like in browser, if possible.
Thank you in advance.
EDIT
Here is MainPage.xaml (modified):
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CBT.MAUI.Blazor"
             xmlns:web="clr-namespace:CBT.Web.Blazor;assembly=CBT.Web.Blazor;"
             x:Class="CBT.MAUI.Blazor.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}">

    <BlazorWebView x:Name="blazorWebView" HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
        <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
            <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type web:App}" />
        </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
    </BlazorWebView>
</ContentPage>

I also tried to enable Serilog, but no file with errors was created.
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .CreateLogger();
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);

The original line with logging to debug doesn't produce any output with errors:
builder.Logging.AddDebug();

Also I copied a Services.

Can you also refer to materials or describe here your experience of similar migration?

In my current project, we have an WASM Blazor app and wanted to have this on desktop. We just created an empty WPF app with BlazorWebView control and show the blazor app inside - which is responsive, by the way. So we have only one code base (the blazor app) and one line of additional WPF code. Works like a charm. Maybe a solution to think about instead of basically duplicating the code to a MAUI app.

So we have the same blazor app running as a windows client and as a website at the same time without code changes.

@decius I've done the same, but getting error, which not displayed. Just switch line ''

you have to post your code, otherwise its hard to tell.

@DavidLevin After switching line <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type web:App}" />, the error still exist? Can you provide more relevant code?

@decius edited code.

Did you try the AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools in your project? you can refer to Use browser developer tools with ASP.NET Core Blazor Hybrid

@ShuowenHe-MSFT thank you for link

First, you need to add builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools(); in MauiProgram.cs file.
For the Windows platform, after running the project, Use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shift+I to open browser developer tools.
For the Android platform, open a new tab in your browser (outside the emulator) and type:
For Chrome: chrome://inspect
For Edge: edge://inspect
For Firefox: about:debugging

Then click the inspect button in the browser.
For more details you can refer to Use browser developer tools with ASP.NET Core Blazor Hybrid
